# How to update SQL Server database withi C# unique Row only?

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I run my program and try to update it, it updates all the columns to the new data in textboxes I don't know how to tell it to do it for the certain username which is in a textbox (`txtUsernameUser.Text`) table name is `UserData` primary key is `Username`. I just want to say thanks in advance for your time

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\Graded unit Dev\BlackMarch\BlackMarch\bin\Debug\DataBaseBM.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE UserData SET Username = @Username, Password = @Password, FirstName = @Firstname, Surname = @Surname, Age = @Age, Gender = @Gender, Mobile = @Mobile, Email = @Email", con);

con.Open();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsernameUser.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtboxPass.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtboxFN.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtboxSurname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtboxAge.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", txtboxGender.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtboxMobile.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtboxEmail.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Comment: you need to use `WHERE` clause inside your update

Comment: The only way that would work is if you had a WHERE statement.  Which you don't.

Comment: Do you know the difference between MySql and Sql Server? Use the appropriate tags in your question

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

Add a `WHERE` clause to the `UPDATE` statement to identify the subset of records which are being identified.  Additionally, you *don't* want to update the Primary Key (since it shouldn't change anyway).  So you can use that parameter and just modify the query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE UserData SET Password = @Password, FirstName = @Firstname, Surname = @Surname, Age = @Age, Gender = @Gender, Mobile = @Mobile, Email = @Email WHERE Username = @Username", con);
```

or, for readability in this post...

```
UPDATE
 UserData
SET
 Password = @Password,
 FirstName = @Firstname,
 Surname = @Surname,
 Age = @Age,
 Gender = @Gender,
 Mobile = @Mobile,
 Email = @Email
WHERE
 Username = @Username
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a proper where condition eg: if you can select the row with a YourID use it

```
"UPDATE UserData SET Username = @Username, 
  Password = @Password, 
 FirstName = @Firstname, 
 Surname = @Surname, 
 Age = @Age, 
 Gender = @Gender, 
Mobile = @Mobile, 
Email = @Email
WHERE YourID = @YourId"
```